# fopen trying to access a different folder

Tags: c

I'm learning how to do file operations and whilst using fopen I seem to have encountered a problem. My project is in **'C:\Users\Bob\Documents'**, however, when I use fopen, it saves or tries to access files from  **C:\Users\Bob\Documents\Debug**. Debug is a folder in my Documents.

1. How can I have my program access files from **C:\Users\Bob\Documents** only and not from the **Debug** folder.
2. Is there a way to specify different locations to save or access files from, instead of the current directory where my project is.

   ```
   int main(){

   FILE *fpointer;
   char ch;
   fpointer = fopen("test.txt", "r");

   while(1){
       ch = fgetc(fpointer);
       if( ch == EOF){
           break;
       }
       printf("%c", ch);
   }

   return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: the current working directory refers to where the project is safe, correct? If so, the working directory is **C:\Users\Bob\Documents** and not **C:\Users\Bob\Documents\Debug**. How come it chooses to save there?

Comment: The current working directory will depend on how your executable is launched, which in your case is probably via an IDE. You should never make any assumptions about this though - the working directory can be anywhere.

Comment: With a lot of IDEs, the working directory of a program when started is the location of the executable.   If X is the name of the directory where your project file is, a sub-directory of X named Debug is often where the executable for a debug build is placed.   Since you haven't specified what IDE you are using, you'll need to read the documentation for how to change such settings (both the output directory - where exectutables are stored - and the working directory when running a program, can often be configured independently).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. I was using CodeBlocks. I managed to change the build settings for one project only by right clicking project ->settings ->general->build-> intermediate folder -> changed from ./Debug to ./

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of what you are asking depends on your development environment.

Your development environment should be offering you some means to somehow configure how your program is launched, by modifying something called "debug configuration" or "launch configuration" or something along these lines.  Note that these options are different from the general options of the development environment, because they differ from project to project.

Right now it appears that nothing is configured, so the current directory of your application is the same directory as the directory where the `.exe` file is.  Since you are running your debug build, the `.exe` file is generated under `Documents\Debug`, and that's its working directory.  So, in the launch configuration specify that you want its working directory to be in `C:\Users\Bob\Documents`.

Alternatively, you can of course try opening "..\test.txt", but this will fail if you ever try to run your `.exe` under deployment conditions, where both the `.exe` and `"test.txt"` are probably going to be in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the debug part. That makes sense. I am using CodeBlocks, so will try and change the debug configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't pass a path to `fopen` it will open files in the current working directory, which happens to be the Debug directory in your case.

Pass a full path instead, e.g.

```
fpointer = fopen("C:\\Users\\Bob\\Documents\\test.txt", "r");`
```

or change the working directory (either programatically, or in your IDE settings).

Comment: **fpointer = fopen("C:\\Users\\Bob\\Documents\\test.txt", "r");**

I tried this, but it didn't work. Can you tell me what you mean by changing it _programatically_? I am trying to change the build settings. 
P.S. I am using CodeBlocks

Comment: @BobJane: does the file `test.txt` exist in your Documents directory?  Windows might be hiding the actual file extension in the file manager and a file showing as `test.txt` might actually have the name `test.txt.doc`...

Comment: `fpointer = fopen("C:/Users/Bob/Documents/test.txt", "r");` is equivalent and slightly less ugly ;-)

Comment: after configuring the build settings (I added how i did it in the comment for my question), I moved the test.txt from ./Debug to the Documents folder. It worked then. Build settings was the key